# is there a python package for Games-Howell multiple comparisons of ANOVA post hoc analysis?

Tags: python, anova, posthoc

after performing Welch's ANOVA test (p < 0.05), a Games-Howell multiple comparisons is needed, but i can't find a python package for this method.

is there a python package for Games-Howell multiple comparisons of ANOVA post hoc analysis?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post about doing it manually: https://aaronschlegel.me/games-howell-post-hoc-multiple-comparisons-test-python.html

Unfortunately there's nothing in `scikit_posthocs`, but there is one here which i'm yet to try: https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.pairwise_gameshowell.html#pingouin.pairwise_gameshowell

Although I imagine if you searched Google you've came across this already. Hope this helps!